# Use dplyr to find rows with specified conditions *and* a set of related rows

Tags: r, dplyr

Using `dplyr` on a data frame of population sizes over time, I'd like to identify the set of time points at which the subpopulations first exceed zero, and also the corresponding set of previous time points (i.e. the latest times before subpopulations exceed zero). I can find the first set of time points as follows:

```
df <- data.frame(time = rep(1:4, each = 3), 
  id = rep(letters[1:3], times = 4), 
  population = c(1, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0))

first_gens <- group_by_(df, ~id) %>%
  filter_(~population > 0) %>%
  summarise_(start_time = ~min(time)) %>%
  ungroup()
```

In this example, the first time points for subpopulations a, b and c are respectively 1, 2 and 3.

What I can't figure out is an easy way to find the previous time points. In this example, the previous time points for subpopulations a, b and c should be respectively NA, 1 and 2 (dealing with the NA case is unimportant as I can filter out such cases).

Edit: I want a solution that works for an arbitrary sequence of time points.

Any help would be much appreciated.

(NB: I'm using "_" forms of `dplyr` functions to satisfy CRAN package requirements.)

Comment: I am not sure if I understand the question. Try min(time) - 1 in your code

Comment: That works in this particular example but not in general. I should have clarified that I'd like the method to work for arbitrary time points, like the solution posted by @julien-navarre.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `lag`

```
df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  summarize(min(time[population > 0]), 
            lag(time)[min(which(population > 0))])

> df %>%
+   group_by(id) %>%
+   summarize(min(time[population > 0]), 
+             lag(time)[min(which(population > 0))])
# A tibble: 3 x 3
  id    `min(time[which(population > 0)])` `lag(time)[min(which(population > 0))]`
  <fct>                              <int>                                   <int>
1 a                                      1                                      NA
2 b                                      2                                       1
3 c
```

Comment: Fantastic! That's exactly what I'd been struggling to do. Nice and succinct.

Comment: In fact, the solution posted by @julien-navarre doesn't work for general time points. For example it fails if I change `time = rep(1:4, each = 3)` to `time = rep(0:3, each = 3)` in the above example.